# moving a movie clip by pressing a button AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Does anyone know how to move a movie clip by clicking a button on the stage.  I can get it to move in increments, but I want it to move constantly.  Currently I have this:

```
down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, arrowDown);

function arrowDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
bottomArrow.y += 1;
}
```

Comment: In your `arrowDown`, start a timer or use an ENTER_FRAME listener to make the changes to `.y`.  In a MOUSE_UP handler, stop the timer or ENTER_FRAME.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394877/as3-run-code-continuously-while-holding-a-button-down-air-for-ios-android/12395009#12395009

Answer (score 1):

First, you should listen for `KeyboardEvent`s instead of `MouseEvent`. Then I think you should listen for those events being dispatched by the `stage`.

Here is an example using the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event. If you'd like to control better the speed of you sprite moves you might want to user a timer instead.

This example works when the down arrow is pressed but you can change `Keyboard.DOWN` with any key you want.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }
}

function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }
}

function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    bottomArrow.y += 1;
}
```